# What am I doing wrong when trying to build this python package using py2exe?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(name='a program',
      version='0.9.1',
      description='does things',
      author='a person',
      author_email='an email',
      license='no license',
      data_files=[('images', 'image1.png'),
                  ('images', 'image2.png')],
      packages=['my_python_package'],
      options={'py2exe':{'includes': ['PyQt4.QtGui', 'PyQt4.QtCore'],
                         'bundle_files':1}})
```

Yet, whenever I run `python setup.py py2exe` from a console, I get the following output:

```
running py2exe
running build_py

  1 missing Modules                  
  ------------------                 
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore4.dll to dist
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll to dist
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'O'
```

I have no idea what this `'O'` thing that is being referenced is. What might I be doing wrong, and how can I check it?